# Updating value of a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am newbie of Django. And I don't understand how Django model works.

First, I am trying to create a model of user score in users/models.py, so each user has a score variable to store their own score, and score can be updated.

Then, in my morse_logs/game1.html, i will ask a question as simple as 1+1 to user, then i retrieve the answer and compare it in morse_logs/views.py to see if it is correct, if it is correct, I will add 5 score to that user; if incorrect, no score is added.

So now I am struggling to define a correct model for setting a field for user to have their own score, and I wonder how can I update and retrieve the score of the user in view.py.

**users/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    #score = models.CharField(User, max_length=10, default=0)


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)


class UserScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=0)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the model"""
        return self.score
```

**morse_logs/game1.html**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <title>GAME 1</title>
    <h1>GAME 1</h1>
    <h2>1 + 1 = ?</h2>
    <input type="number" id="ans1" name="ans1"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" name="game1Answer">Decipher</button>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**morse_logs/views.py**

```
@login_required()
def game1(request):
    """The Game 1 page"""
    val1 = request.GET.get('ans1', '')
    res = "Incorrect"

    if val1 == 2:
        #user's score declared in model increase 5points
        #display correct and 5 points added to user
        res = "Correct"
    else:
        #user's score declared in model has no point
        #display incorrect and 0 point added to user
        res = "Incorrect"

    return render(request, 'morse_logs/game1.html', {'result': res})
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have probably the wrong field type for storing this store information.

I would go with an `IntegerField`:

```
score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Because you have changed from a CharField to an IntegerField, you will need to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to resolve your database with the changes.

Then, in your views you would want something like this, utilising the `get_or_create` method for looking up an object with the given `**kwargs` (may be empty if your model has defaults for all fields), creating one if necessary.

Reference here: https://kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.QuerySet.get_or_create

```
@login_required()
def game1(request):

    if request.user and not request.user.is_anonymous:
        user = request.user
    else:
        # Throw some raised exception here as the user is not valid...

    """The Game 1 page"""
    val1 = request.GET.get('ans1', '')
    res = "Incorrect"

    user_score = UserScore.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

    if val1 == 2:
        #user's score declared in model increase 5points
        #display correct and 5 points added to user
        res = "Correct"
        user_score.score += 5
        user_score.save()
    else:
        #user's score declared in model has no point
        #display incorrect and 0 point added to user
        res = "Incorrect"

    return render(request, 'morse_logs/game1.html', {'result': res})
```

Comment: It prompts me this error: AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'IntergerField'

Comment: You need to import it, so use `score = models.IntegerField`, I think there was a spelling mistake...

Comment: @Din Sorry there was a spelling error - it should have been `models.IntegerField()` - remove the "r" from Integer...

Answer (score 0):

Change your views.py to

```
@login_required()
def game1(request):

    if request.user:
        user = request.user
    else:
        #throw exception

    """The Game 1 page"""
    val1 = request.GET.get('ans1', '')
    res = "Incorrect"

    if int(val1) == 2:
        #user's score declared in model increase 5points
        #display correct and 5 points added to user
        user_data = UserScore.objects.get(user=user)
        res = "Correct"
        user_data.score = int(user_data.score) + 5
        user_data.save()
    #no need to write else part  

    return render(request, 'morse_logs/game1.html', {'result': res})
```

Comment: it gave me this error: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (score) specified for User

Comment: is userscore table is in your database? Do check it.

Comment: If you have done changes in your database then do this **python3 manage.py inspectdb > models.py(your model)**

Comment: I can not see it in my django admin, nothing is updated, I can only see User profiles under User.

When I did python manage.py migrate, it gave me this: django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "new__users_userscore" has more than one primary key

And when I try to do runserver it gave me this: You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): users.

Comment: And now when I load the page game1.html, it shows "OperationalError at //game1/", the next line shows "no such column: users_userscore.id"

Comment: it is now showing "No installed app with label 'UserScore'."

Comment: go to settings.py and add the app name to INSTALLED_APPS list.

Comment: go to apps.py copy the class name(it should be UserScoreConfig) and add to settings.py  **UserScore.apps.UserScoreConfig**

Comment: Why my class name is UsersConfig instead?

Comment: Do you have github Repository of your project? Provide the link if you have.